# Error during SMTP installation

Tags: magento-2.1

I try to install extension Magento 2 SMTP.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

So I downloaded the extension and upload FTP to folder:
app/code/Mageplaza/magento-2-smtp-master

Then I run the SSH command:

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

php composer.phar require mageplaza/module-smtp
```

When I run this command I get error, below is screenshot. Anyone know how to solve it ?

[image]

Comment: can you run command `ls -all` to see if the ownership's are correct?

Comment: I run this command and please check photo: https://image.ibb.co/cfaODb/error2.png Is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your terminal:

`sudo chown -R user ~/.composer`

**Make sure you replace user with your current user**

Comment: it looks like the rights are correct for the user from whom I run the commands. https://image.ibb.co/cfaODb/error2.png What do you think about it ?

Comment: type `which composer` in you terminal and tell me what you get

Comment: I run which composer but not get any information. https://ibb.co/cKdUKG

Comment: Did you manage to get it sorted?

Comment: I have refreshed the topic because I have a problem with running your command sudo chown -R user ~/.composer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210233/error-during-installation-smtp-extension